# sailsjs v0.10 express customMiddleware not loading

Tags: express, sails.js

Can anyone tell me how to load customMiddleware, or any function that gets the express app, in sails v0.10?

In the past you could, inside /config/express.js, have the following:

```
customMiddleware: yourFunc(app){
  //do stuff including
  // app.use(myMiddleware)
}
```

This member of express.js is no longer called in v0.10 - at least not by default.  You can prove this to yourself by creating a new app with "sails new" and defining a new function in config.express.customMiddleware. It won't fire.

Does anybody know how to enable this?  Or is there another place or config option to enable me to get access to the express app at startup?

Comment: Could you mark the provided answer as accepted if it works for you? Just for the records.

Comment: yes, i haven't been back here lately, sorry it took me so long!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify an additional config for `config.express.costumMiddleware` to be mounted. By setting `config.middleware.custom` to `true` you enable this default behavior of previous Sails versions.

```
// config/express.js
module.exports.express = {
  middleware: {
    custom: true
  },

 customMiddleware: function(app){
    // express middleware here
 }
};
```

**Related commit**

[a89a883c22](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/commit/a89a883c22b141f89636d0b1064aa830bcd94786#diff-7b114f92a7603b943a0ead8e0a1e8d6cR32)

**Related source**

[sails/lib/hooks/http/load.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/9a9e8ce6f45ee8b9da87a91a052e18ed8a3efc8b/lib/hooks/http/load.js#L147)

Comment: FYI this is unintentional behavior that will be fixed in the next patch, so that setting `custom:true` is no longer necessary for your custom middleware to run.  But leaving that key in there will not have any ill effect, so this answer is still valid!

Answer (score 6):

Handling of the `customMiddleware` has slightly changed in Sails 0.10. In version 0.10 that method needs to be configured in `http` hook (not `express` hook, as in previous version).

It is also very important to remember that your `sails.config.http.middleware.order` list needs to have `'$custom'` middleware entry in it as that will trigger custom middleware function to run.

So in order to add any custom initialization, you can add the following change to the `/config/http.js` file:

```
module.exports.http = {
    // ...
    customMiddleware: function(app) {
        // do something ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to perform environment dependent customization, say, in production, you can add following changes to the `/config/env/production.js`

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    http: {
        customMiddleware: function(app) {
            // do something in production environment
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

I use that approach to enable *trust proxy* express flag.

Example:

```
...
   http: {
    customMiddleware: function(app) {
        app.enable('trust proxy');
    }
  }
...
```

Code handling can be found on Sails Github: [/sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/load.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/http/middleware/load.js).

BTW, when using express hook in Sails 0.10, you will get following warning:

> warn: `sails.config.express` is deprecated; use `sails.config.http` instead.

Comment: Note that `customMiddleware` [goes under `module.exports.http`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/http/middleware/load.js#L23), *not* `module.exports.http.middleware`.